# Where is documentation for the iTunes API on OS X?

Tags: macos, itunes

I'm trying to find an API to control iTunes on OS X.  I found the following:

http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html

I imagine on OS X, what I need is built in, but I have no idea where the API is documented?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, There is only an SDK (via COM) for Windows.

In Mac OS, iTunes is controlled via AppleScript.

There are quite a few tutorials running around, but I'm not familiar with anything official. In fact, last time I looked, they gave links to third-parties.

e.g., [Tutorial](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info01.php)

Comment: If you wan't to "listen" track change events, you might look at this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888816/objective-c-mac-os-x-distributed-notifications-itunes

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Cocoa then I would recommend the (non-apple) framework [EyeTunes](http://www.liquidx.net/eyetunes/).

Applescript may be your best bet though, either through calling a script directly or the ScriptingBridge framework available for [Ruby, Python](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/UsingScriptingBridge.html), and [Objective C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html).

For the documentation, look at iTunes script dictionary (drag the iTunes icon onto the Script Editor icon).

Comment: Sadly EyeTunes hasn't been updated since 2008, and iTunes is now a cocoa application.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the API spec for the OSX applescript interface then run the AppleScript Editor (comes with OSX) and select File->Open Dictionary and choose iTunes from the list.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Karelia's iMedia Browser](http://www.karelia.com/imedia/). [Source](https://github.com/karelia/imedia) available under a BSD-style license.