# Objective-C Mac OS X Distributed notifications iTunes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications, itunes, scripting-bridge

i need a little help, i currently have a method; updateTrackInfo in my Mac OS X application which gets the artist name, the track name and duration of the track currently being played in iTunes

However i want the app to listen for the distributed iTunes notification; **com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo** then call the method updateTrackInfo when ever the notification is distributed by iTunes. Please could someone help me, on what i would need to write in both the header and implementation file.

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for [`-[NSDistributedNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000396-addObserver_selector_name_object_):

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateTrackInfo:) name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" object:nil];
```

Elsewhere in the same class...

```
- (void) updateTrackInfo:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSDictionary *information = [notification userInfo];
  NSLog(@"track information: %@", information);
}
```

It even gives you a whole bunch of track information in the notification.  Isn't that nice?

Comment: This works great most of the time, but doesn't notify me when the current song is _stopped_, i.e. there is now _no_ current song.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help, you helped me correct my code, I had this written up:

```
- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (!self) return nil;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
                                             name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo"
                                           object:nil];
return self;}

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
if ([@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" isEqualToString:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo"]) {
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}}
```

But it used NSNotificationCenter instead of NSDistributedNotificationCenter. Which is where I was going wrong.

Thanks, Sami.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.  As a side note, the `if()` statement in your `-receiveNotification:` method will always be true...