# Get audio metadata from current playing audio in iTunes on OS X

Tags: swift, macos, audio, itunes

I am writing an app in Swift on OS X. Is there a way to get the current playing audio in iTunes? I would like to get details such as title, artist, etc.

What I've found already:

1. [Here is an Objective C example, but not all those methods are available with Swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452555/control-itunes-from-a-cocoa-application)
2. [This example uses AppleScript, which I might have to do. But I'd rather use Swift if possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744832/get-list-of-tracks-and-filenames-or-a-way-to-play-them-from-itunes-on-os-x)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple example how to get the properties from the current track:

Tested on (`El Capitan v10.11.5`, iTunes **12.4** and Xcode **7.3**).

```
import Cocoa
import ScriptingBridge
@objc protocol iTunesApplication {
    optional func currentTrack()-> AnyObject
    optional var properties: NSDictionary {get}
    //if you need another object or method from the iTunes.h, you must add it here
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let iTunesApp: AnyObject = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iTunes")!
        let trackDict = iTunesApp.currentTrack!().properties as Dictionary
        if (trackDict["name"] != nil) {// if nil then no current track
            print(trackDict["name"]!) // print the title
            print(trackDict["artist"]!)
            print(trackDict["album"]!)
            print(trackDict["playedCount"]!)
            // print(trackDict) // print the dictionary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails in Xcode 11 with `Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'currentTrack'` at the `trackDict` declaration line

Comment: Try changing `com.apple.iTunes` to `com.apple.Music`.