# How would i play a specific song in iTunes through java?

Tags: java, controls, itunes, playback

How would i play a specific song in iTunes through java?

I assume I need to somehow connect to iTunes and use the play function with a certain parameter....Can anyone point me in the right direction to learning how to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't recall iTunes having any programmable API, so I doubt you can do this without some sort of dirty-hack

Comment: I'm trying to make a program, where one of its features is to play a certain song inside of iTunes.  I have a vbscript that can do it, but I want to incorporate it in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664949/where-is-documentation-for-the-itunes-api-on-os-x) answer, there is no API. There is only an SDK (via COM) for Windows.
In Mac OS, iTunes is controlled via AppleScript([example](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info01.php)).

Comment: Isn't there some sort of way I'd be able to hook into the program and use its functions? or send a command to it at least?

Comment: I'd like it to work on windows

Comment: so you can use the SDK via COM... To use it, there is a java-com bridge http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ I haven't used it, but should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Ik it's too late, but u can use apple script editor. for instance,

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                String[] args = {"osascript" , "-e" , "tell application \"iTunes\" to play"};
                try{
                Process process = runtime.exec(args);
                }catch (Exception ex) {                 
                }
```

this will play a song in itunes