# How to control iTunes through winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, itunes

I can see a similar question that has been answered here ([How would i play a specific song in iTunes through java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872600/how-would-i-play-a-specific-song-in-itunes-through-java)) but it doesn't really answer my question (I don't think, anyway).

I have a couple of buttons on a winform (play, pause, skip forward, skip back) and want to be able to connect these through iTunes, so as to create a 'mini media player'.

However, I am having issues (obviously, or I wouldn't be writing this :P) with all this 'COM' malarkey. I have tried including (nearly) all the possible references from 'Apple', 'iTunes' and still can't seem to be able to find a way of pressing the button 'play' and actually playing a song in iTunes.

I have a button on click event (i've called the button `btnPlay`). But does anyone know the 'correct' or 'efficient' way of connecting iTunes to winforms?

I've heard about something called `sendKeys`, but I'm a total noob and have really no idea of how to create this sort of thing.

PS. I've also tried to find a refence for `using iTunesLib;` (from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/07/06/automating-itunes-with-c-in-net.aspx) but this is a dated post, and i'm not certain this namespace is available anymore (well, I can't find it anywhere in the `Com references` anyway.

As always, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hi - did my answer work for you? - I was able to get iTunes to play using the answer below

Comment: @ajg - I haven't tried it yet, but from recollection I didn't see that reference (will look this evening) and will post tomorrow?

Comment: OK - I've got iTunes 11.2.2.3 installed and my reference is called 'iTunes 1.13 Type Library'

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to iTunes 1.xx Type Library (it will be in the COM list of references).

Then you can use iTunes app as so in your click event

```
iTunesApp app = new iTunesAppClass();
app.Play();
```

you will need to perform the [following step](http://www.peschuster.de/2012/06/interop-type-itunesappclass-cannot-be-embedded/) to embed the the COM iTunes app.

```
Go to the Solution Explorer.
Right click on References –> iTunesLib and hit Properties.
Set “Embed Interop Types” to False.
```