# Is it possible to open a movie in iTunes with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, itunes

I'm developing a C# application that needs to be able to tell iTunes to open a .m4v file on Windows. Is this possible? I've tried on Command Prompt to do this but it just opened iTunes without opening the movie. Is there any iTunes command line arguments or am I out of luck?

Edit: Also, once the movie is launched, is it possible to control it, such as playing, pausing, or closing it?

Comment: I always used to get a message "One or more applications are using the iTunes Scripting Interface" when trying to quit, so at some point it has been scriptable yes. But I can't find any docs for it, only people complaining about that error message :-/

Comment: Just call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` on the file and let Windows pick the app to open the file with.

Comment: @Dour High Arch Yes, but then I would want to be able to control iTunes after opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet might be **iTunes COM object** ([How to control iTunes through winForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605098/how-to-control-itunes-through-winforms))

but I'm not sure if it's going to support action such as loading file into an iTunes, but if you are about to control it like play/pause, fast forward, rewind etc. then this is what you should looking at.

Comment: Ok. I followed that link and also downloaded the "iTunes COM Interface" from Apple's website. However I'm confused as to how to add it to my project, as there's only a C++ code file and a C++ header file in the SDK. Those would have to be compiled, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You may find it in Visual Studio -> Project -> Add Reference -> COM, and search for iTunes (which will appear after you install the iTunes) edit : not sure if win10 install via store include this DLL or not, but the legacy installer from apple.com is included.